# How to prevent the execution of the same Sub called in NEW() constructor a lot of times while objects are inherited?- vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oop, inheritance, constructor, interface

First of all: I have *3 interfaces*, each has some class holding required assembly & license data,the first two interfaces are implemented by the next one(s): **ISolution --> IExtension --> IExportPlugin**, and their objects are inherited from the base class - Solution.

**ISolution** can be implemented by any application, at least to provide licensing features.
**IExtension** is a base for the *IExport*, *IImport*, *IService* etc - I planned a lot of derivatives, if it will be neccessary, the license checking is required for every type of extension (plugin).

Each derivative class initiates the calling *LicenseCheck* sub in New() of base class, which shows frmActivate dialog if the license not found.

So, in inheritance, it shows ACTIVATE **three times!!!**.
Say, please, can I prevent this window showing, except the last time, when IExportPlugin created?

Yes, I can add optional parameter 'OmitLicenseChecking', but it`s not the best idea due to security reasons.
Every program (exe or dll) must incapsulate it without any possibility to avoid checking. E.g. Checking is a must and must be hidden.

Thanks, friends.
And sorry for my English))

Comment: A minimal code example of your current implementation would work better than a description if you can post something.

Comment: ...or a Unit Test where you show how a Plugin uses your code

Comment: There`s the principle/approach more important than any code.No matter what code does - a question was about how to lock multiple execution of the part of constructor))

Answer (score 1):

A guess based on the information provided

```
Public MustInherit Class Solution
    Public Shared Lock As New Object
    Public Shared Shown As Boolean
    Public DoShow As Boolean

    Public Sub New()
        SyncLock Lock
            If Not Shown Then
                Shown = True
                Me.DoShow = True
            Else
                Me.DoShow = False
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class SolutionA : Inherits Solution
    Public Sub New()
        If Me.DoShow Then
            Stop
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class SolutionB : Inherits Solution
    Public Sub New()
        If Me.DoShow Then
            Stop
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class SolutionC : Inherits Solution
    Public Sub New()
        If Me.DoShow Then
            Stop
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

To test, where the Stop represents the dialog,

```
    Dim foo3 As New SolutionC
    Dim foo2 As New SolutionB
    Dim foo1 As New SolutionA
```

Comment: Thank you so much,I`ll try it tomorrow)